# how to protect secret from application log in spring cloud vault?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config

we am trying to use vault to keep database credentials and using token in by spring boot application to fetch secrets. Credentials are kept at secret back-end at vault. Connection with application and vault is secure to TLS. This kind of secret distribution is still vulnerable and depends on the developers maturity. Once application has the access to secrets it can be logged in the files. Unlike traditional JEE application, data source is looked up in resource jndi and application never now the database credential. resource setup was done by operations team and access to credentials were limited. Application never has the credential visibility.

Is my understanding correct, if that so how we can make secrets more secure in spring boot application or is this the trade off we have to compromise with.

Answer (score 1):

Very Good Question.

As I think secrets can be logged in the files. As we are getting from vault.
We have to compromise on this. Its same as any secure information (eg. customer data) regarding application can also be logged in the files.

It should be taken care by developer and reviewer.